# Bottomsheet shows over RecyclerView - How to make sure clicked item is shown in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

Im using a `CoordinatorLayout` with an `RecyclerView` and hidden `BottomSheet`. When the User `clicks/selects` an Item in the `RecyclerView` the `BottomSheet` gets expanded, often it hides the clicked item of the `RecyclerView`.

How can i make sure that the Clicked item is shown ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just scroll the `RecyclerView` to the position of the item clicked after the `BottomSheet` fragment is opened:

```
myRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(clickedItemPoistion)
```

If you are wondering how you get the position, it's in your `onBindViewHolder()` in the adapter.

Comment: When an Item gets clicked which is close to the end of the list, how can this work ? the recyclerview itself would need to scroll then

Comment: hmmmm, well you can try to resize the recyclerview perhaps?

Comment: from my perspective this is a common use case, or im wrong here? i researched a bit but could not find an app doing it like this

Comment: I personally have never done it, but just a brainstorm idea, you can try replacing the elements of the list and place the one clicked in the middle and than scroll to it....